# error array required, but Personal found¿por que me sale tal error?

Tags: java, array

en la parte de p[cont]= me da el error

```
public class AdmonPersonal {
   private Personal p[];
   private int cont;
   
   public AdmonPersonal() {
      p = new Personal[99];
      cont = 0;
   }
   
   public boolean hayEspacio() {
      if (cont < p.length) {
         return true;
        } 
        return false;
      }
      
      public boolean validarId(int id) {
         if (id >= 1 && id <=100) {
             return true;
             }
             return false;
             }
             
      public int busqueda(int id) {
         int celda = -1;
         for (int x=0; x<cont; x++) {
          if (id == p[x].getid()) {
               celda = x;
               break;
             }
            }
            return celda;
          }
          public  void altas(Personal p){
            p[cont]= p;//error: array required, but Personal found
            cont++;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Hay ambigüedad entre la variable local `p` y la variable de instancia `p`. Resuelvelo con: `this.p[cont] = p`

Comment: si me funciono gracias!